# Проблема с ClientSide DataSource: Grid не принимает данные

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, java

Есть Grid, хочется на него повешать filter search. Для этого гриду необходим datasource. 
Если сначала отображать grid потом присоединить datasource, grid не принимает данные. 
Наоборот получается нормально, но не вариант: форму нужно отображать вначале.

DataSource вот такой

```
class XmlDS extends DataSource {
private static XmlDS instance = null;

public XmlDS(String string) {
    setID(id);
    setClientOnly(true);

    DataSourceIntegerField pkField = new DataSourceIntegerField("id");
    pkField.setHidden(true);
    pkField.setPrimaryKey(true);

    DataSourceTextField name = new DataSourceTextField("a", "ФИО");
    name.setRequired(true);

    DataSourceTextField email = new DataSourceTextField("b", "e-mail");

    setFields(name, email);

}

@Override
public void processResponse(String requestId, DSResponse responseProperties) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.processResponse(requestId, responseProperties);
}

public static XmlDS getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new XmlDS("XmlDS");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Что делаю не так скажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. У DataSource есть метод setTestData(DataClass[] data), он работает только для setClietOnly(true) DataSourcев. Таким образом можно задать дату в любой момент, даже после отображения. Только не забыть list.invalidateCache()